# Are helper functions in Meteor reactive?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

Suppose I have the following code in my HTML file:

```
{{#if someVar}}
    {{>someTemplate}}
{{/if}}
```

Now, if initially `someVar` returns `false` then the `someTemplate` Template is not created. Now, due to some event, the value returned by `someVar` is `true` will the template be rendered or not? Do I need to make `someVar` a `ReactiveVar` for this to work? Or should I use `autorun`? Which is the best and easiest method to do this? This can be achieved quite easily with 2-way binding in Angular.

Comment: if the variable, returned by `someVar` is a reactive data source, then it will re-run.

Comment: Yes a ReactieVar or any other reactive data source will re-run automatically within a helper

Answer (score 0):

Considering the given template above:

```
{{#if someVar}}
    {{>someTemplate}}
{{/if}}
```

#### Non-Reactive Example

```
var someNumber = 42; // changing this will not cause a new run

Template.theTemplate.helpers({
  someVar() {
    return someNumber;
  }
});
```

### Reactive Example 1

```
var someNumber = new ReactiveVar(42); // changing this will cause a new run

Template.theTemplate.helpers({
  someVar() {
    return someNumber.get();
  }
});
```

### Reactive Example 2

```
Template.theTemplate.onCreated(function onCreated() {
  this.someNumber = new ReactiveVar(42); // changing this will cause a new run
});

Template.theTemplate.helpers({
  someVar() {
    return Template.instance().someNumber.get();
  }
});
```

The forementioned 2-way binding is achieved automatically using ReactiveVar oder ReactiveDict.